# js Object - changing multiple, specific Properties with a single Method

Tags: javascript, object, properties

i am trying to build an object that contains various 'settings / options' for the rest of the page as properties.
These propierties can be changed by different events like dom interactions and so on.

A bit simplified my object looks like this

```
var settings = {
  opt1: false,
  opt2: false,
  opt3: true,
  opt4: true,

  change: function(a, b, c, d){
     this.opt1 = a,
     this.opt2 = b,
     this.opt3 = c,
     this.opt4 = d,
  }
};
```

Lets say i needed to change opt4, i would have to pass the current value or do something like if conditions for the first three elements as well.

Is there a way where i can have one function for the changes but also tell which options should be changed? maybe someting like

```
settings.change({opt4:false});
```

thank you very much

Comment: I wonder why you don't simply do `settings.opt4 = false`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
settings.change = function(obj) {
    for (var p in obj) this[p] = obj[p];
};
```

obj must be an object like you wrote in your question.

```
// sets opt2 to string 'two', opt4 to number 77
// and inserts a new option opt33 with value 'new'
settings.change({opt2: 'two', opt4: 77, opt33: 'new'});
```

If you want to remove an option completely:

```
settings.remove = function(name) {delete this[name];};
```

name must be a string (quoted).

```
// after this there is no opt3 inside settings any more
settings.remove('opt3');
```